# How to post a request with raw body in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to post this raw body with Alamofire, how I can do it?

```
[
    {
        "x": 234,
        "y": 1,
        "z": 10648
    }
]
```

Comment: "I want to..." is not a question it is a requirement. This is a Q&A site.

Comment: In addition to @Scriptable remark: can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score -3):

Please try this:

```
let param = ["x": "234", "y": "1", "z": "10648"]
Alamofire.request(requestURL, method: .post, parameters: param as? Parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseJson) in
     print("Response : \(responseJson)")
     if (responseJson.result.isSuccess){
         //Sucess Part

     } else {
          //Fail part
     }
}
```

Comment: 123 is not string it is Int